# How to set image on Button and add rounded edges through xml on Android?

Tags: android, xml, image, button

I've found several solutions on how to do this through the activity but I'd much rather stick to using xml for layout and graphics.

I want to set an image on a button with rounded edges instead of the plain default corners.

XML SAMPLE:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/featuredimage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded"
                android:src="@drawable/budlight_sample"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

ROUNDED.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shape drawable for rounded corners , define a rounded.xml in drawable folder of your app.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
    <corners
        android:radius="integer"
        android:topLeftRadius="integer"
        android:topRightRadius="integer"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
        android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
</shape>
```

ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

In your layout.xml file use the the rounded.xml as background for your view.

```
android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

Comment: I was using "android:background=@drawable/img" to put my image in the background, so how would I do this now since I can't use duplicate android:background descriptions?

Comment: no you can't use multiple android:background , Use image view set android:src = "your image" , android:background= "your shape "and   android:clickable="true"

Comment: The image is still a rectangle, any more ideas?

Comment: first change shape to rectangle and remove your src image for time being and check if you are getting the rounded corners

Comment: Alright, I changed it to rectangle and added <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> so I could see it against my black background and it has rounded edges without the image.

Comment: then after adding image if the effect is getting lost i guess you should add round corners to your image

Comment: I figured out by adding android:cropToPadding="true" to the xml it crops the picture inside of the rounded corners for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Draw a shape in an xml file and then call it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#Anycolor" android:endColor="#Anycolor" 
            android:angle="90"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Another option is to use draw9patch. But, you will have to create a custom image button for that. Much easier to use the code above.

Comment: I was using "android:background=@drawable/img" to put my image in the background, so how would I do this now since I can't use duplicate android:background descriptions?

Comment: If you have an image that you want to use as a button AND you want to add rounded corners to that button you can do two things I believe. `android:background=@drawable/img | @drawable/rounded` Not sure if that would work though. The easiest way I believe would be to add rounded corners to your image in photoshop, and use draw9patch or create multiple sizes of the image for compatibility.